# Is it "if you need further instruction" or "if you need further instructions"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Having a debate with a friend about whether it is "instruction" or "instructions"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on what meaning you intend to convey.

> **[Instruction](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instruction)**   (ɪnˈstrʌkʃən)
>   
> *n.*
>
> 1. the act or practice of instructing or teaching; education.
>
>    knowledge or information imparted.
>
> ---
>
> instruction. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010).

In your example, "further instruction" would denote the first meaning, somebody teaching you, while "further instructions" would denote the second, more information.

Comment: Example: "I need further instruction"="I need someone to teach me more so I can become good at this task" whereas "I need further instructions"="I need someone to give me the steps I need to take to complete this specific task"

Comment: As long as I am here, I feel as if I should mention that this answer seems incomplete, since it does not yet explain why the plural or non-plural status of the word instruction makes it more likely to be interpreted as one meaning one of these definitions over the other.

Answer (score 4):

One would interpret *'instruction'* as ***'what to do'*** and *'instructions'* as ***'steps explaining how to do something'***.

*"For lack of further instruction, the platoon decided to take a break."*
vs.
*"The apprentice followed my instructions to the letter."*

The actual sense here is that ***instruction*** is the uncountable form of ***instructions***. Also, *instruction* might refer to a whole new task while *instructions* would mean the next set of steps in a task you're already doing.

Referring to your question, *"if you need further instruction"* would give the impression of *"if you want to know what is your next task*" and *"if you need further instructions"* would mean *"if you need to be told what to do next in whatever you're trying to do right now"*.

I think you need the second one. But it really depends on what you wish to imply.

Hope I could make myself clear enough.