# Resuming its normal "operation" or "operations"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases, expressions

Which one is correct when you write office close notice:

1. The office will resume its normal operations on Monday, DD/MM/YY...
2. The office will resume its normal operation on Monday, DD/MM/YY...

If both are right, which one is more commonly used?

Comment: Is the office considered to perform one operation or multiple operations?

Comment: "its" should be omitted. The office cannot resume anyone else's operations. :)

Comment: Both are grammatical, but @Greybeard's suggestions are better. // Plural, or singular-form non-count? Your choice. Do you want to emphasise multiple operations or work as usual?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it "if you need further instruction" or "if you need further instructions"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258976/is-it-if-you-need-further-instruction-or-if-you-need-further-instructions)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both are correct. They are both understandable and unambiguous.

To me, “resume normal operations” implies that it will resume its normal tasks.

And “resume its normal operation” implies that it will operate in its normal manner.

These implications are both clear and mean the same thing.